# Using Python to send twitter data directly to Google Cloud data storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, data-storage

How might one send data from Twitter directly to Google Cloud data storage. Would like to skip the step of first downloading it down to my local machine and then uploading it up to the cloud. It would run once. Not looking for full code, but any pointers or tutorials that someone might have learned from. Using python to interact with google-cloud and storage.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your use case? Do you need the information streamed constantly or just retrieve it when a script is ran and that's it? What have you tried so far? Directly asquing for code or "do this for me" kind of stuff don't tend to go well on StackOverflow. I would recommend reading [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the SO help center.

Comment: Edited a bit now. But looking more for pointers/tutorials that could help. The google documentation is often confusing and very general.

Comment: Hey Magnus, you're saying that you don't want to download to your machine, but something needs to be running your logic. Cloud Storage just stores data, and Twitter doesn't have a data export function, just an API (which you must program against).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's a blog post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/twitter-analytics-part-1-801c9d494487) which describes the following architecture:

- Run a Python script on Compute Engine
- Moving your data to BigQuery for storage

[Here's another one](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/analyzing-tweets-using-cloud-dataflow-pipeline-templates) that describes a somewhat more complex architecture, including the ability to analyze tweets:

- Use Google Cloud Dataflow templates
- Launch Dataflow pipelines from a Google App Engine (GAE) app
- In order to support MapReduce jobs